# Ampersand, bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ampersand

I used to use

```
{\rm \&}
```

for ampersands in the bibliography, but it is deprecated, and leads to an error with scrbook document class.

If I remove the "\rm" it looks like this:

[image]

But what I want is this

[image]

but actually better in italic.

Comment: `\rm` hasn't been defined by default in latex since 1993, use `\textrm{\&}` but the form you show _is_ the usual italic form in most fonts.

Comment: This question also deals with ampersands in an italic environment: [Ampersand symbol algorithm environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298333/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The italic version of the ampersand in Computer Modern just looks like the first picture you posted. But you could use the slanted version of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\&               % or {\upshape \&}
{\itshape \&}
{\slshape \&}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

If you want to change the appearance of & in the whole document to it’s non-italic version, you could make use of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310695). For example as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\&}{%
  \nfss@text{%
    \upshape\symbol{`\&}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textit{one \& two}

\textbf{one \& two}

\texttt{one \& two}

\end{document}
```

This way, the & will always be non-italic, but bold face or changing to another font will still work. However, take care that this may lead to bad kerning (especially between the non-italic & and an italic letter that follows) and, of course, it prevents you from entering an italic &. Also, it is possible that this breaks due to incompatibilities in certain situations.

Comment: The slshape is working. However, \rm actually creates the 2nd symbol, which must be the default at that spot. Is there a way to override the default and make it not italic?

Comment: `\textrm` actually sets the font family to a roman (= serif) font, regardless of its shape (italic or not). You can use `{\upshape \&}` to achieve this effect. Do you want to override the default shape for the whole document at once?

Comment: Actually, overriding for the whole document would be even better! That way I would not have to mess with my bib files.

Comment: Overriding in the whole document does not work for me, it seems to mess up other stuff relation to caption tables. ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.

Comment: That’s what I feared would happen. Actually, it is probably a bad idea to override a character, because it can be used in several different ways and some of them may break. It is nearly impossible to tell in advance where it could break. So, it will be probably better if you avoid such overriding and just use “search and replace” to solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe, this approach could also help in case you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224584/define-fallback-font-for-specific-unicode-characters-in-lualatex